# Concatenate multiple ranges using vba

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I have a number of ranges to concatenate independently and put the values of the concatenated ranges into different cells.

I want to:
concatenate values in Range A1:A10 and put the result in F1
then concatenate the Range B1:B10 and put the result in F2
then concatenate the Range C1:C10 and put the result in F3 etc.

The following macro concatenates range A1:A10 and then puts the results into F1 (which is what I want). However it also stores the information from the first concatenation into memory so that when it does the next concatenation, in cell F2 I get the concatenated results of F1 and F2 joined.

```
Sub concatenate()

    Dim x As String
    Dim Y As String

For m = 2 To 5

    Y = Worksheets("Variables").Cells(m, 5).Value 

    'Above essentially has the range information e.g. a1:a10 in sheet variables

    For Each Cell In Range("" & Y & "") 'i.e. range A1:A10
        If Cell.Value = "" Then GoTo Line1 'this tells the macro to continue until a blank cell is reached
        x = x & Cell.Value & "," 'this provides the concatenated cell value
    Next

Line1:

    ActiveCell.Value = x

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Next m

End Sub
```

Comment: Right before `Next m` insert simple statement: `x=""`

Comment: Oh you Genius! I wasted my entire day on this! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Here is my ConcatenateRange. It allows you to add a seperator if you please. It is optimized to handle large ranges since it works by dumping the data in a variant array and working with it within VBA.

You would use it like this:

```
=ConcatenateRange(A1:A10)
```

The code:

```
Function ConcatenateRange(ByVal cell_range As range, _
                    Optional ByVal seperator As String) As String

Dim newString As String
Dim cellArray As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

cellArray = cell_range.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(cellArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(cellArray, 2)
        If Len(cellArray(i, j)) <> 0 Then
            newString = newString & (seperator & cellArray(i, j))
        End If
    Next
Next

If Len(newString) <> 0 Then
    newString = Right$(newString, (Len(newString) - Len(seperator)))
End If

ConcatenateRange = newString

End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

... I would do this very differently... Why not create a function along the lines of:

```
Function ConcatMe(Rng As Range) As String

Dim cl As Range

   ConcatMe = ""

   For Each cl In Rng
      ConcatMe = ConcatMe & cl.Text
   Next cl

End Function
```

And then just, for example, set F1 = `ConcatMe(A1:A10)` or, then write code to assign the function to the cells you want...

Or, as @KazJaw mentioned in his comment, just set `x=""` before re-looping.

Hope this helps

Comment: + 1 I was about to paste almost a similar suggestion but had to abort since you posted an answer :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout ... I've had the same happen with some of your solutions... I guess great minds think alike :)

Comment: One suggestion though... `Function ConcatenateRange(rng As Range, Sep As String)` Where Sep is the separator ;)

Comment: I am sure there are easier ways to do this, I had no idea what x "" actually does? It somehow takes out of memory the last loop or something? Also NO idea you can do a function in vba like this. However, because I have 30/40 rows I would have to set F1 to F30 separately I think, that's why I wanted to do an overall for next statement e.g. for m = 2 to 20. then it would loop automatically 20 times. I will have a play with this. but the x = "" works!

Answer (score 3):

it is similar to the idea posted here already. However, I use a for each loop instead of an array setup with nested for loops.

```
Function ConcRange(ByRef myRange As Range, Optional ByVal Seperator As String = "")

ConcRange = vbNullString

Dim rngCell As Range

For Each rngCell In myRange
    If ConcRange = vbNullString Then
        If Not rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
            ConcRange = CStr(rngCell.Value)
        End If
    Else
        If Not rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
            ConcRange = ConcRange & Seperator & CStr(rngCell.Value)
        End If
    End If
Next rngCell


End Function
```

This, I suppose would be faster than the array set up, as a new array is not created each time this function runs.

Answer (score 2):

Right before Next m insert simple statement: x="" –  KazimierzJawor Apr 8 '13 at 20:43

took me several minutes to notice this answer was under comments :p

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everything guys, for my purpose I have modified your suggestions and amended my code as it didn't quite fit into a neat function as I needed it to be more dynamic. See my code below. It does exactly what I need.

```
Sub concatenate()

Dim x As String
Dim Y As String

For Q = 1 To 10 'This provides a column reference to concatenate - Outer For statement
For T = 1 To 10 'This provides a rows reference to concatenate - Inner for statement

For Each Cell In Cells(T, Q) 'provides rows and column reference
If Cell.Value = "" Then GoTo Line1   'this tells the macro to continue until a blank cell is reached
x = x & Cell.Value & ","   'This provides the concatenated cell value and comma separator
Next ' this loops the range

Next T  'This is the inner loop which dynamically changes the number of rows to loop until a blank cell is reached

Line1:
On Error GoTo Terminate 'Terminates if there are less columns (max 10) to concatenate

ActiveCell.Value = Mid(x, 1, Len(x) - 1) 'This basically removes the last comma from the last concatenated cell e.g. you might get for a range 2,3,4, << this formula removes the last comma to
'give 2,3,4

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Once the concatenated result is pasted into the cell this moves down to the next cell, e.g. from F1 to F2

x = ""  'The all important, clears x value after finishing concatenation for a range before moving on to another column and range


Next Q 'After one range is done the second column loop kicks in to tell the macro to move to the next column and begin concatenation range again

Terminate: 'error handler
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@Issun's solution doesn't accept output from a worksheet array formula as the argument for the 'cell_range' parameter. But a slight modification to @Issun's code fixes this. I also added a check that ignores each cell whose value is `FALSE`.

```
Function ConcatenateRange( _
        ByVal cellArray As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal seperator As String _
            ) As String

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim newString As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = 1 To UBound(cellArray, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(cellArray, 2)
            If Len(cellArray(i, j)) <> 0 Then
                If (cellArray(i, j) <> False) Then
                    newString = newString & (seperator & cellArray(i, j))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If Len(newString) <> 0 Then
        newString = Right$(newString, (Len(newString) - Len(seperator)))
    End If

    ConcatenateRange = newString

End Function
```

For example:

```
A       B       (<COL vROW)
------  ------  -----------------
one     1         3
two     1         4
three   2         5
four    2         6
```

Enter into cell C1 the formula below and press CTRL+ENTER to store the formula as an array formula:

```
{=ConcatenateRange(IF(B3:B6=1,A3:A6),CHAR(10))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking further to see if there is a better way of writing concatenate function and found this. It seems that we all have the same working principle for the function. So its ok.

But my function is different that it can take multiple parameters, in combination of ranges, texts and numbers.

I assume that a delimiter is mandatory, so if i don't need it i just put "" as the last parameter).

I also assume that blank cells are not to be skipped. That's the reason why i want the function to take multiple parameters, so i can easily omit those that that i don't want in the concatenation.

Example of use:

`=JoinText(A1:D2,F1:I2,K1:L1,";")`

You can also use together text and number among the parameters:

`=JoinText(A1:D2,123,F1:I2,K1:L1,"PQR",";")`

I'd love to hear any comments or suggestions where it can be improved.

Here is the code.

```
Public Function JoinText(ParamArray Parameters() As Variant) As String
    Dim p As Integer, c As Integer, Delim As String

    Delim = Parameters(UBound(Parameters))

    For p = 0 To UBound(Parameters) - 1
        If TypeName(Parameters(p)) = "Range" Then
            For c = 1 To Parameters(p).Count
                JoinText = JoinText & Delim & Parameters(p)(c)
            Next c
        Else
            JoinText = JoinText & Delim & Parameters(p)
        End If
    Next p

    JoinText = Replace(JoinText, Delim, "", , 1, vbBinaryCompare)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `ConcatenateRange` to concatenate all cells in range if they are not empty and empty "" string.

```
  Function ConcatenateRange(cellRange As Range, Optional Delimiter As String) As String
    Dim cel As Range, conStr As String

    conStr = ""
    If Delimiter <> "" Then
      For Each cel In cellRange
        If VarType(cel) <> vbEmpty And Trim(cel) <> "" Then conStr = conStr & cel & Delimiter
      Next
      ConcatenateRange = Left(conStr, Len(conStr) - Len(Delimiter))
    Else
      For Each cel In cellRange
        If VarType(cel) <> vbEmpty And Trim(cel) <> "" Then conStr = conStr & cel
      Next
      ConcatenateRange = conStr
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score -5):

**Its very simple brother,** Look out of the Excel. No need for all cumbersome formula or VBA.

Just copy all the cells that you need to concatenate and paste it in the notepad. Now just select the space between the lines/columns (it's a TAB space actually) and find and replace it.. Done.. All cells are concatenated. Now just copy and paste it in the column and just verify.. Thats it :) Enjoy.

I suggest you to use Notepad++ for this :) Koodos

**Vimarsh
Ph. D. Plant Biotech.**
/

Comment: this is no good answer. the question wasn't how to avoid excel. and you suggest instead installing another programm, which is not neccessary and selecting a tab space - what most of the regular users do not even understand