# VBA: Invalid Next Control Variable Reference

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors, concatenation

Basically, i'm trying to mimic a concatenate result using code i stripped apart and recycled for my purposes. But i'm having problems when the script attempts to process "Next T" idk, but i already indicated as a Dim - Integer, and that still didnt seem to do the trick.

Original source of code: 
[Concatenate multiple ranges using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888353/concatenate-multiple-ranges-using-vba)

I've been having a lot of problems with  this one piece, cause it seems to be the only thing i've actually been trying to include in my script for a long time now. Had compile errors with closing the If, adjusting the Then, and even Exiting the loop.

I think the Next should be my final worries.

Btw, rnumbers is supposed to hold the place of a value/integer, but i'm not entirely sure if that was done correctly either.

```
    rnumbers = Rows(ActiveCell.Range("A3").End(xlDown)) + 3
    'or CellCount = ActiveCell.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xldown).Row

    Do While Rows(ActiveCell.Range("A3").End(xlDown)) > 3

        'For Q = 1 To 10 'This provides a column reference to concatenate - Outer For statement
        For T = 3 To rnumbers 'This provides a rows reference to concatenate - Inner for statement

            For Each Cell In Cells("A" & T) 'provides rows and column reference
                If Cell.Value = "" Then
                    GoTo Line1   'this tells the macro to continue until a blank cell is reached
                    Exit For
                End If
                x = x & Cell.Value & Chr(10)   'This provides the concatenated cell value and comma separator
            'Next ' this loops the range

        Next T  'This is the inner loop which dynamically changes the number of rows to loop until a blank cell is reached

        Line1:
        On Error GoTo Terminate 'Terminates if there are less columns (max 10) to concatenate

        ActiveCell.Value = Mid(x, 1, Len(x) - 1) 'This basically removes the last comma from the last concatenated cell e.g. you might get for a range 2,3,4, << this formula removes the last comma to
    'give 2,3,4

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Once the concatenated result is pasted into the cell this moves down to the next cell, e.g. from F1 to F2

        x = ""  'The all important, clears x value after finishing concatenation for a range before moving on to another column and range


        'Next Q 'After one range is done the second column loop kicks in to tell the macro to move to the next column and begin concatenation range again

    'rnumbers = 0
    'Next
    Exit Do
    'Resume
    Terminate:'error handler
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying again... when I took a closer look at your code I actually used a Bad Word.

You have been hanging with the wrong crowd, and are picking up some really bad code structure ideas. A `GoTo` followed by an `Exit For`? The latter statement can never be reached!  And jumping out of a `For` loop is a dangerous (if not wrong) thing to do. And yes, you still needed a `Next` for the `For Each` statement (with a matching control argument - the `Next T` belonged with a different For loop, not the innermost one).

Anyway - I felt like [the Cat In The Hat](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/41305-and-this-mess-is-so-big-and-so-deep-and): "This mess is so big and so deep and so tall - we cannot pick it up, there is No Way At All!".  So I decided to build you a new house instead.

I think the following does what you want to do, and quite elegantly. See if it makes sense, and if you can adapt it for your purpose. I need to go to sleep but will take a look in the morning to see if you figured it out from here.

```
Sub concAll()
Dim allRows As Range, target as range
Dim oneRow
Dim nc as Integer

Set allRows = Range("A3", "J10")  ' pick the real range here - dynamically, probably
nc = allRows.Columns.Count        ' need this number later to know where to put result

For Each oneRow In allRows.Rows   ' loop over one row of the range at a time
  Dim s As String
  s = ""                          ' start with empty string
  For Each c In oneRow.Cells      ' loop over all the cells in the row

    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
      s = s & "," & c.Text
    Else
      Exit For                     ' done with this row: found empty cell
    End If

  Next c                           ' keep looping over the cells...

  Set target = oneRow.Cells(1).Offset(0, oneRow.Cells.Count) ' cell where we put result
  target.Value = Mid(s, 2)   ' put the concatenated value to the right of everything; 
                             ' skipping first comma (which came before first text)
Next oneRow                  ' repeat for all rows in source range


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out to comment and assist with my troubles. The first comment you made, about the next being a comment and active. Turns out it was an extra next, that i commented out, to help the script flow without any compile errors, i left that comment there to reminds me of changes and adjustments that were made. Helps better my progress and correctional skills especially when i look back. I changed the variable as well from T to 'rcell' and that also prompted the same error. i posted rest of script. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, i shouldve explained what i was trying to produce than asking to fix something i wanted to do. My experience in vba has been self-taught, and i'm a little new to asking for help.

The script Floris produced seemed to have function but not as intended. Turns out what i wrote is a little outdated, and needs to be wiped and restarted. This was actually an old script i started a few months back that worked off of a web-query. But the website went thru some changes and now the script is all over the place.

the main issue i was having was a compile-error "Invalid Next Control Variable Reference" Which turns out to be caused by an open 'Do while' loop, that doesnt seem to have much of an exit point from the research i looked up. Was supposed to have used another 'If' command instead. At the same time, when attempting to solve that 'Do While' i added an extra 'Next' (cause i thought they were compatible), and it screwed with the script.

Hard to explain.. But the 'Do While' i used, i wanted it to combine the values only if the number of values were greater

```
rnumbers = Rows(ActiveCell.Range("A3").End(xlDown)) + 3
'or CellCount = ActiveCell.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xldown).Row

Do While Rows(ActiveCell.Range("A3").End(xlDown)) > 3
```

But instead it was supposed to be

```
Dim CellCount As Range

CellCount = ActiveCell.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row + 2
'cause its the active cell + two additional cells

If CellCount > 3
```

Which then opens up into the script Floris submitted. (But that failed too, because of what was stated above).

Thanks again, hope that it explains everything... Sorry if i wasted your time with that one Floris, really do appreciate the assistance. Just wish i had asked for the help sooner, would have saved me a lot of frustration that i'm dealing with now. >_>