# Why is VBA throwing type mismatch errors when passing a Range object?

Tags: .net, vba, excel, type-mismatch

I have this function (which I based off a function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888353/concatenate-multiple-ranges-using-vba)):

```
Function Foo(ByVal r As range) As String
    MsgBox "WHAT. The function worked? Wow!"
    Foo = "test"
End Function
```

I have tried calling it like so:

```
Let max_row = cells.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
Set r = range(cells(2, ID_COL), cells(max_row, ID_COL))
Foo r
```

And I Always Get the Error: "run-time error 13, type mismatch" once the code hits the call to Foo.

Additionally, I have tried:

```
Foo (r)
```

Which gives the error: "Object Expected" 
I assume this means that parentheses deference a pointer to its value, and are not (always?) used in function/subroutine calls.

I have also tried writing the function without the "ByVal" but that failed as well.

Any ideas?

EDIT Tried what @ScottCraner suggested but the error remains:

```
Dim text As String
Let max_row = cells.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
Set r = range(cells(2, ID_COL), cells(max_row, ID_COL))
text = Foo(r)
```

EDIT Important Note: this is being run from a Macro Enabled Word Document, the Excel Library is imported and the workbook is opened from the code.

Comment: A function returns something so you need to have it equal something.  Like: `t = Foo(r)` or change it to a sub instead of a function and call it like this: `Foo r`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code syntax. Is that the actual calling code? On an unrelated note, saying VBA is bad or inadequate just because you don't understand its workings is foolish.

Comment: Sorry, for got that bit when typing it into the question (see edit). I tested again with the same result. Additionally, I agree! It is foolish to say a language is bad before you understand how it works. That's why I said "probably." I'd call it an educated guess.

Comment: Why do analog watches exist?  Why do corded phones exist?

Comment: You still need to have something in the calling sub into which the result will go.  Instead of `Foo(r)` put `Dim t as string: t=Foo(r)`

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the line Foo(r)? If you wrote, for example, MsgBox Foo(r) then you would get a message box with the string output. Your line by itself doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Learn about VBA and using  functions and subroutines online - I'm sure the example you found showed you the proper way to call and use it.

Comment: The function is a test, to try to figure out why I cannot a call another similar function. That is why is appears pointless: I simply removed everything else to narrow what I needed to look at.

Comment: Did you try what I, or @ChrisMelville suggested?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it still does not work. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Why are you using columns in your row? Let max_row = cells.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count then cells(max_row, ID_COL))  also what is ID_COL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem turned out to be that because this code was run from word, with the Excel library as a reference, the Range type defaulted to a MS-Word Range object instead of a MS-Excel Range object, meaning that my function was looking for the wrong type of parameter. Here is the corrected code (notice the explicit reference to the Excel lib when defining Foo and the Range variable r):

```
Function Foo(r As Excel.Range) As String
    MsgBox "WHAT. The function worked? Wow!"
    Foo = "Test"
End Function

Sub main()
    Set workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open("example.xlsx")
    Set datasheet = workbook.ActiveSheet

    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = datasheet.Range("A2:A100")
    Dim t As String
    t = Foo(rng)
    Debug.Print t
End Sub
```

As @ScottCraner and others pointed out the issue could easily have been that I had a variable/function called Range defined somewhere else. In a way that is sort of what happened, only it was defined in the Word Library, not in my code.

Comment: You should edit your original question to reflect the fact that there was a confounding factor, and that resolving that resolved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

When using the `()` you need to assign it to a variable or other direction:

```
Function Foo(r As Range) As String
    MsgBox "WHAT. The function worked? Wow!"
    Foo = "Test"
End Function

Sub fun()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A2:A100")
Dim t As String
t = Foo(rng)
Debug.Print t
End Sub
```

[image]

You can also just use `Foo rng` or `Call Foo(rng)`

Thanks to the ever correct @Rory

---

But the real issue seems that you have used the word `range` as a variable, sub or Function elsewhere and this is superseding the correct usage of it as an object.

As was pointed out by @Mat'sMug

Comment: That code cause a mismatched  type error on the line "Set rng = range("A2:A100")" However, it is probably worth mentioning the VERY INTERESTING FACT that my vba editor immediately auto replaces all instances of "Range" with "range".

Comment: @tumbleWeed101 dude, VBA is case-insensitive, and the VBA IDE (the glorious VBE) automatically formats a number of things. If you want to freak out, declare a local variable `Dim range As String` and see what happens to all the `Range`s everywhere. Oooooooooh magic!

Comment: @tumbleWeed101 as Mat's Mug just said, you have declared range as a variable somewhere, either as a variable, sub or function.

Comment: OMG that's gotta be it! @tumbleWeed101 if `Range` gets corrected to `range` then you've got a variable or something named `range`, and if that something is in scope then that's what you're calling. Replace your unqualified `Range("...")` calls with `ActiveSheet.Range("...")` (i.e. make these implicit active sheet references explicit).

Comment: FYI a function doesn't *have* to return anything, nor do you have to use its return value even if it does. The original code worked as posted (barring the `range` issue)

Comment: Interesting because when I did it it gave me the object error. @Rory See http://imgur.com/Cl3J1c5

Comment: The original code was not `foo (r)` (which is wrong) - it was `foo r` which is fine.

Comment: As would be `Call foo(r)`

Comment: @Rory well color me pink and call me "pretty".  Now I need to figure out how to edit the answer as the comments here are what found the true error, so I do not want to delete it.

Comment: I'll just dig out my Psychedelic Furs album... :)

Comment: I have ctrl-f searched the entire document. There is no variable range. I think there used to be one though. I will try rebooting the editor, maybe it was remembering a since deleted variable named "range". It will have to be tomorrow though, as I just left work.

Comment: I rebooted the computer and the problem with auto-replacing went away, but the problem remains. However I am almost certain I know what the problem is now. I did not know that there was a Range object for Word as well as Excel, and I think when I define something as Range it defaults to the Word object. This explains just about everything. I just need to figure out how to reference the Excel lib Range explicitly, or I suppose I could make the function take a variant.