# Delete spaces in body of Outlook mail generated with RangetoHTML function

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

This code copies a particular range of cells, each cell (having codes like 1ML-234-1R) and places it in the body of an Outlook mail. (Taken from Ron de Bruin Excel Automation code.)

I want to delete spaces that appear in the body before and after each cell and to separate each cell value by comma(,). Used trim command but had no luck.

```vb
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "faizanfarooque@hotmail.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Load Shed "
        .HTMLBody = Trim(RangetoHTML(rng))
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

[image]

I want it to be like this

[image]

Comment: what spaces? an image would make it more clear. by the way are you talking about the Center alignment, `align=center` in your html?

Comment: @cyboashu added pictures for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RangeToHTML function you are using is designed to port the given range and maintain it's existing structure in HTML format. If you just want a list of values in a range delimited with a string, you can use a much simpler function like:

```
Function fnConcatRange(rng As Range, Optional delim As String) As String

For i = 1 To rng.Count
    fnConcatRange = fnConcatRange & rng(i)
    If i < rng.Count Then fnConcatRange = fnConcatRange & delim
Next

End Function
```

And then put them in your email like

```
.HTMLBody = fnConcatRange(rng, ",")
```

You can also append any HTML tags as strings if you want to format your e-mail body in a particular way.

There are more thorough concatenation functions than this one (like the one found here: [Concatenate multiple ranges using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888353/concatenate-multiple-ranges-using-vba)), but it should do what you need.