# List (data validation) comprising of text and cell references

Tags: excel

I am trying to combine hardcoded text ("hello") and cell references ($A$1:$A$2") to a data validation List in Excel.

Tried everything, incl. =AND("Hello",$A$1:$A$2") or ="Hello, "&$A$1:$A$" or even "Hello"+A$1:$A$2 but nothing works.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: The list of cells is much longer than just two, hence why I am trying to find a solution that does not involve listing them out individually :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
="Hello"&TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,$A$1:$A$2")
```

Alternativly, you can also use the `CONCATENATE`function:

```
=CONCATENATE("Hello",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,$A$1:$A$2"))
```

Comment: Hey! The list of cells is much longer than just two, hence why I am trying to find a solution that does not involve listing them out individually :-)

Comment: Thank you for coming back so quickly! For some reason I still get an error message when I paste both alternatives into the formula box. I have tried doing this with the Data Validation set to List and also Custom. None of them works :( Any thoughts on what the issue may be?

Comment: I think this may be due to the fact that I am using Office 2016 and Textjoin isnt a function that exists. Tried creating it in a Module on VBA but the line of code you suggest still doesnt work (with and without concatenate)

Comment: Yeah, you need Office 365 or 2019 for ´textjoin´. To solve it with VBA, check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888353/concatenate-multiple-ranges-using-vba

Comment: For some reason even after creating the function on VBA the List or Custom formula still desnt work... though the ConcatenateRange function works in the actual Excel spreadsheet... What a headache :-(